# ssh-askpass error from sshpass/ssh

Tags: ssh

One of our suppliers delivered a new embedded system for us to test and one of my bash test scripts is failing with:

```
sshpass -p xxxxxx ssh  -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" root@rpi-2 "Do stuff"
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib64/misc/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied, please try again.
```

It appears they have upgraded to Ubuntu (from Gentoo):

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

A google search led me to this forum where another thread (link removed)  indicated a similar issue that was solved by installing an ssh-askpass package.
Checking with apt list, I find there is no ssh-askpass installed on this system which I believe is the root cause of my issue.
My problem is of course, most of this system is read-only and I cannot do any apt installs (at least none that would modify /bin /lib /usr etcetera).

I was under the impression ssh-askpass was used in a GUI environment and was not required for CLI invocations of ssh. While X is installed here, it is not involved in the session I am running from. Both DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS are unset in my environment.

So I am wondering if there is a workaround for this problem or is my only alternative to go back to the supplier and ask them to include ssh-askpass package in their distribution which they might do but will take at least one development cycle (months) to approve.

The end goal is simply to remote execute a bash script on a Raspberry Pi from the embedded system via the LAN with no user interaction (i.e. no password prompt).

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered using public key authentication instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

```
export SSH_ASKPASS=/var/bin/my_ssh-askpass
```

contents:

```
# my_ssh-askpass: Provide password to ssh
echo "password"
```

Comment: You could use your variable inline so its not permanently set in the environment.  `$ SSH_ASKPASS=/var/bin/my_ssh-askpass ssh  -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" root@rpi-2 "Do stuff"`